# PHP cURL one post but twice (dual) it's the same data to database with api

Tags: php, curl

So i use custom website api and i one post data with php curl.
Everything is fine, but the data appears twice (dual) in the database.
Why stored data twice in database?
i try on/off RETURNTRANSFER,FOLLOWLOCATION, VERBOSE.
I try ob_start, ob_get_contents, ob_end_clean.
but there will always be double data in the database :(

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $pw);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type: multipart/form-data']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Expect:']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json']);

$adat = [];

$adat['data[sortOrder]'] = 1;
$adat['data[status]'] = 1;
$adat['data[productsStatus]'] = 1;
$adat['data[groupCode]'] = NULL;
$adat['data[parentCategory][id]'] = '';
$adat['data[centralCategory][id]'] = '';
$adat['data[categoryDescriptions][0][name]'] = 'Test cat 1';
$adat['data[categoryDescriptions][0][description]'] = 'Test cat 1 desc';
$adat['data[categoryDescriptions][0][language][id]'] = 'bGFuZ3VhZ2UtbGFuZ3VhZ2VfaWQ9MQ==';


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $adat);

//ob_start();
$response = curl_exec($curl);
//$response = ob_get_contents();
//ob_end_clean();

if ($response === false) {
     echo curl_error($curl);
}

$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$httpReturnCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$lastURL = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$data = substr($response, curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
                
curl_close($curl);
                      
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($data));
echo '</pre>';

log file
*   Trying x.x.x.x:80...
* Connected to api.url.example.address (x.x.x.x) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> POST /categoryExtend HTTP/1.1
Host: api.url.example.address
Authorization: Basic 
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 1144
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------b05e0dbf7a681e1e

* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: openresty/1.13.6.1
< Date: Sat, 08 Apr 2023 18:36:36 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 1205
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, public
< Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; report-uri /csp_logger
< Expires: Sat, 08 Apr 2023 18:36:36 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; report-uri /csp_logger
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
< X-WebKit-CSP-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; report-uri /csp_logger
< X-LB: api
< X-LB: api
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.url.example.address left intact
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that this script could be (accidentally) called twice?

Comment: how about turning on `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, can you confirm that it posted twice? if you have access to web server's access log, it may help to confirm whether your code sending post request twice

Comment: I attached it log file content

Answer (score 1):

you are calling the curl function 2 times with the if statements as $response has already been allocated. replace response with curl_exec($cur)

```
$response = curl_exec($curl) // remove this
if (curl_exec($curl) === false) { echo curl_error($curl); }
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

You can use this function at the bottom to curl to a remote server and echo json_encode($data) to return response.

```
$cz=curl_exec($response);
$b=json_decode($cz, TRUE);
if($b[0] == "successfull"){ }
```